# App crashes on receiving push notification

Tags: android, firebase, android-layout, gradle, push-notification

Everything was working fine, but as per requirements from play store, i upgraded my app to `api level 27` and all play-store libraries to version `15.0.0`, app started crashing on receiving push notifications.

Now when i send push notification app crashes with following error message.

```
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: abstract method "void com.google.firebase.iid.zzb.zzd(android.content.Intent)"
    at com.google.firebase.iid.zzg.run(Unknown Source:29)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
    at com.google.android.gms.common.util.concurrent.zza.run(Unknown Source:7)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

This is my code, i have only integrated `channels` here, and it was working fine, when `play-services` were set to version `9.0.0`

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
    String from = remoteMessage.getFrom();
    Map data = remoteMessage.getData();
    Log.d("MSG", "onMessageReceived: "+data);

    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
    Set<String> keys = remoteMessage.getData().keySet();
    for (String key : keys) {
        try {
            jsonObject.put(key, remoteMessage.getData().get(key));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    try {
        SharedPreferences appPrefs = mContext.getSharedPreferences(SHARD_PREF, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String notifcation_settings = appPrefs.getString(NOTIFICATION_ENABLED, "");

        message= jsonObject.getString("message");

        if(!jsonObject.isNull("urlToOpen")){
            urlToOpen= jsonObject.getString("urlToOpen");
        }

        sendNotification(message, urlToOpen);

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}





private void sendNotification(final String msg, final String urlToOpen) {


    Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
    handler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            NotificationManager notificationManager= (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            Uri soundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);


            notificationIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
            notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
                    | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

            intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0,
                        notificationIntent, 0);
            }



            Long getCurrentTime= System.currentTimeMillis();
            int id= Math.abs(getCurrentTime.intValue());

            mBuilder = new Notification.Builder(mContext);


            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                createNotificationChannel();
                mBuilder.setChannelId(getResources().getString(R.string.notification_channel_general));
            }

            mBuilder
                    .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setContentIntent(intent)
                    .setContentTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.notification_title)).setContentText(msg)
                    .setStyle(new Notification.BigTextStyle().bigText(msg))
                    .setSound(soundUri)
                    .build();

            notificationManager.notify("packageIid , mBuilder.build());
        }
    });
}



private void createNotificationChannel() {

    String CHANNEL_ID= getResources().getString(R.string.notification_channel_general);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        CharSequence name = getString(R.string.channel_name);
        String description = getString(R.string.channel_description);
        int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT;

        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, name, importance);
        channel.enableVibration(true);
        channel.setDescription(description);
        channel.enableLights(true);

        NotificationManager notificationManager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
    }
}
```

These are my gradle settings.

**Build.gradle(Project)**

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.0'
```

**build.gradle(app)**

```
compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion "27.0.1"

   defaultConfig {

        applicationId ''
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 285
        multiDexEnabled true
        resConfigs "en"

    }

resolutionStrategy {

        force 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.4.0'
        force 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.4.0'
        force 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.1.1'
        force 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.1.1'
        force 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.1.1'
        force 'com.android.support:design:24.1.1'
        force 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.0'
        force 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.0'
        force 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth-base:15.0.1'
        force 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:15.0.0'
        force 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.0'
        force 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:15.0.0'
        force 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wallet:15.0.0'
        force 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:15.0.0'
        force 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:15.0.0'
        force 'com.google.firebase:firebase-common:15.0.0'
        force 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:15.0.0'
    }


    dependencies {

    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'

    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:15.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:15.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth-base:15.0.0'
        implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-panorama:15.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.0'
    implementation('com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:15.0.0') {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    }
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:15.0.0'

    implementation 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.8.3'

    }
```

**gradle-wrapper.properties**

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-all.zip
```

Comment: Test case try this `notificationIntent = new Intent(MyFirebaseMessagingService.this, MainActivity.class);`

Comment: Any particular reason why you don't go to the latest updates of `Firebase` and `play-services`?

Comment: @NileshRathod : Now i am getting this error message `Broadcast of Intent { act=com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT flg=0x14 cmp=com.our.package.name/com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdInternalReceiver (has extras) }`

Comment: @Yupi : The same settings are working fine in another project, so i am going save by using the same settings, but looks like same setting are not working on this project.